# Vue image modal open on click

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I'm working on a simple Vue app that has images that I would like to open in a bootsrap modal when clicked on.

I've been reading through various tutorials and solutions, but I still can't figure out how to finish off the modal. I have the images displaying, but I can't figure out how to get the image to show in a modal when clicking on it.

Here is what I have so far:

**Vue component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="row" v-if="othersImages">
      <div id="others-images" class="grid">
          <div class="grid-item" v-for="image in othersImages" :key="image.id">
              <h5>{{ image.name }}</h5>
              <picture v-bind="'image' + image.id">
                <img v-bind:src="image.image.path" v-bind:alt="image.description" 
                @click="showModal"/>
              </picture>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="image-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'othersImages',
  created() {
    this.fetchImages();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      apiRequest: new this.$request(),
      othersImages: [],
      errors: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      // Not sure what to put here?
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#others-images{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.modal-dialog{
    max-width: 75vw !important;
    .modal-content{
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        .modal-body{
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            img{
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
            h5{
                color: $gold;
                font-weight: 700;
                margin-top: 15px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
            p{
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
            .close{
                position: abs(absolute);
                border-bottom: none;
                border-top-left-radius: 0;
                border-top-right-radius: 0;
                right: 15px;
                bottom: 15px;
                color: $text_colour;
                text-shadow: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to control modals in an app.

Here's some additional beginner steps you could try:

1 - Define parameters that will hold the state of the modal (simply true/false to represent show/hide), and something to hold the modal content (in a more mature modal system, you wouldn't hold onto content like this... why store it twice?):

```
data() {
    return {
      // ...
      modalShow: false,
      modalContent: null
    };
}
```

2 - Add a `v-if` on the modal element. The modal will show/hide according to the state parameter.

```
<div id="image-modal" v-if="modalShow" ...
```

3 - Pass content into your `showModal()` method

```
... @click="showModal(image.image.path)"/>
```

.

```
showModal(content) {
  this.modalShow = true
  this.modalContent = content
}
```

4 - Make modal content render inside the modal

```
<div class="modal-body">
   {{ modalContent }}
</div>
```

Exactly what content you pass in the `@click` event, and how you interpret it in the modal is another question. What is exactly that you want to show inside the modal? Just a single , with no controls? It could be as crude as swapping a src url for an image element.

---

Ultimately to leverage the true power of Vue, you probably want to make your own "Modal.vue" component, which you'd use globally across your app (imported once, in the root). It could have props that control whether it's a full-screen modal, whether user-closing is enabled, whether the background page is scrollable, what kind of transition it has, etc.

You would probably want to use an event bus to open/close it, and send content into it. You would also probably make use of `slots` in the template for the modal (e.g. modal slots like 'header', 'content', 'footer'). This is what I do for modals in all of my Vue apps.

The above ideas are the exact same you'd implement in a React app (or other tech). Basically you're decoupling and abstracting things.

Whatever the case, you don't need bootstrap for any of this, but hey if you like using it, feel free. I recommend learning Vue without bootstrap muddying the waters.

Answer (score 0):

For a particular image to be loaded on click of it, you need to pass it as the param of the function then get it in your variable that you insert in the img src.
Like this:

pass the selected img as a param

```
<div class="grid-item" v-for="image in othersImages" :key="image.id">
          <h5>{{ image.name }}</h5>
          <picture v-bind="'image' + image.id">
            <img v-bind:src="image.image.path" v-bind:alt="image.description" 
            @click="showModal(image.image.path)"/>
          </picture>
      </div>
```

then you load the img path in a variable:

```
data() {
return {
  // ...
  modalShow: false,
  selectedImgPath: ''
};
}
methods: {
    showModal(imgPath) {
      this.selectedImgPath = imgPath
      this.modalShow = true
    }
  },
```

Terminate by displaying modal and the selected img:

```
<div id="image-modal" v-if="modalShow" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img :src='selectedImgPath'/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

That should be it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can see in debugging that it's passing through the image path to the "showModal" method, but something seems to be going wrong after that.

I put a breakpoint on the line with <div id="image-modal... > but it never reaches the breakpoint. I'm getting this warning in the console:

2
[Vue warn]: v-bind without argument expects an Object or Array value

found in

---> <OthersImages> at src/components/OthersImages.vue
       <Home> at src/views/home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

Comment: the problem is the use v-bind without an attribute on the <picture> tag 
<picture v-bind="'image' + image.id">
if is an id use <picture v-bind:id="'image' + image.id">

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you the solution with a simple code snippet for better understanding.

In the code snippet, we use the `show_modal` method to change the content of `modal` and then open the modal.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      modal_image_path: "",
      images: [{
          id: 1,
          path: "https://i.picsum.photos/id/42/100/100.jpg?hmac=H5fOEzyhxakVIBdXzI4E5EQ9Fox99YKCeCO7dwSzLFY"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          path: "https://picsum.photos/100/100"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    open_modal(image_path) {
      this.modal_image_path = image_path
      this.$bvModal.show('showImageModal')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 450px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper>div {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-modal id="showImageModal" title="BootstrapVue">
    <b-img-lazy :src="modal_image_path" />
  </b-modal>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div v-for="image in images" :key="image.id" @click="open_modal(image.path)">
      <b-img-lazy :src="image.path" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```